# D3js Tooltip on country MAP is not coming

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Working one:
http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/17/

Not working one when
http://ranjan720.github.io/

Source code:
https://github.com/ranjan720/ranjan720.github.io

iN MAP CHART I USED:

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);
```

PIE CHART WHICH i USED:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .html(function(d) {
            return d.data.population;
        })
        .direction('s')
    svg.call(tip);

    svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(function(d) {
            return pie(d.ages);
        })
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.data.name);
        })
        // SHOW/HIDE TOOLTIP
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.State;
        });
```

Comment: Try with changing d3.js files, like d3.v3.min.js and latest d3 version js file, try with different versions of d3.js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m = d3.map(datas, function(d) {
  if(d.Year == $("input[name=Year]:checked").val()){
    return d.STATEUTS.toUpperCase();
}});
```

keep above lines of code inside mouseover callback,
Before `var id = d3.select(this).attr('id');` this line.

Hope this will work for you...
If not ask for more.

Comment: It's my pleasure...
:D